# Insert the existing value and sort it from another table

Tags: php, sql, database

Insert the existing value and sort it from another table

I'm trying to call data from table A and but table A is sorted from table B.

Detail: Table A stores "ID" and table B stores numbers, I want to sort table A based on the numbers in table B.

I tried the code below but it didn't work

```
$result = $db->Query("INSERT INTO `session`(`id`)VALUES('".$id['tableA']."' ON SELECT * FROM `tableB` WHERE `number`<'500' )") ;
```

After I run the code does not save to the database.

I hope the experts can solve my problem. thank you

Comment: `session` this is your table or  `tableA` ?

Comment: session is another table to store the results of tables A and B.

Comment: There is no syntax I know of that involves INSERT ON SELECT

Comment: Yes, maybe it's a wrong and strange code, but I mean I want to sort table A based on table B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the `ON` in your syntax as the right query is:

```
INSERT INTO [table] SELECT * FROM [anothertable]
```

as [explained in detail in MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

As for your situation, the right query should be:

```
INSERT INTO `session`(`id`) SELECT `id` FROM `tableB` WHERE `number` < 500;
```